# Why does "$x$ multiple of $y$" make the subadditivity property non-strict?

Tags: inner-products

Why does "$x$ multiple of $y$" make the subadditivity property non-strict?

I tried plugging in $x=\lambda y$, but upon quickly viewing the L.H.S. of the triangle inequality.
$$\|x+y\| \leq \|x\| +\|y\|$$
as
$$\|\lambda y + y\|$$
I don't see where the equality comes from?

Comment: $\|\lambda y+y\| = \|(\lambda+1)y\| = (\lambda+1)\|y\| = \lambda\|y\| + \|y\|= \|\lambda y\| + \|y\|$. Personally, I like to make a drawing and get some feeling for why these distances are equal.

Comment: The fact that norms are positively homogeneous does it (it won't work ith $\lambda=-1$, for instance).